# Find the equation of the chord of contact AB of tangents drawn from an external point $(X1,Y1)$ to the parabola $X^2=-36y$

Tags: parametric

Q: Find the equation of the chord of contact AB of tangents drawn from an external point $(X1,Y1)$ to the parabola $X^2=-36y$

My working:

Let $A(2aA,aA^2), B(2aB, aB^2)$

-> Equation of chord AB $ y=\frac{A+B}{2}x-aAB$

-> Point of tangent intersection $[a(A+B), aAB]$

--> $X1=a(A+B)$

--> $Y1=aAB$

---> $y=\frac{X1x}{2a} - Y1$               since a=9

-> Equation: $18(y+Y1)=X1x$

-> However the answer is $-18(y+Y1)=X1x$

What am I doing wrong, is a allowed to be negative?

Comment: Why your expressions for $A$ and $B$? Neither $A$ nor $B$ are in the parabola (only when $a=3$,  is it your trick?)

Comment: isn't 'a' the focal length? and isn't AB a chord?